# Django pre_save, instance is None

Tags: python, django

I am writing the pre_save method to create the slug for model, for some reason my instance is none.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Employee)
def pre_save_employee_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(" ".join([instance.name, instance.surname, instance.id]))
    instance.slug = slug
```

Error is :

```
File "E:\Work\hire_handler\employees\models.py", line 60, in pre_save_employee_receiver
    slug = slugify(" ".join([instance.name, instance.surname, instance.id]))
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Comment: No, the *primary key* is `None`, and that makes perfect sense, since before creating the object at the database side, the item has *no* record.

Comment: If you need to have slug generation after id is set you should use post_save or even better just override save method instead as signals should be last resort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, the `instance` is not `None`, the *primary key* (`instance.id`) is `None`.

That makes perfect sense, before creating the object at the database side, the item has *no* primary key, since database dispatches a primary key.

If you thus want to work with a primary key, you need to work with a `post_save` item, furthermore likely the `id` is an int, so it will still not work, since `' '.join()` can not join integers.

You can use a `post_save` trigger, and save it again, but that will result in making two queries when you create a new `Employee`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def post_save_employee_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.slug = slugify(f'{instance.name} {instance.surname} {instance.pk}')
        instance.save()
```

Furthermore [signals are usually a bit of an antipattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/), especially since when you for example perform `.bulk_create()`, `.update()`, etc. the signals are not triggered.